# Spark Streaming Twitter "receiver-supervisor-future-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter

I am using Spark Streaming Twitter package to fetch the popular hashtags. To be specific, I am trying to replicate this code https://github.com/andrewrgoss/udemy-spark-scala/tree/master/twitter_streaming

I ran the following commands on Windows command line :

sbt package

spark-submit --packages org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:2.1.0 --class com.andrewrgoss.spark.PopularHashtags \target\scala-2.11\twitter_streaming_2.11-0.1.jar

This gives me the below error.

```
2018-04-20 03:16:30 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 172.24.20.2, 56082, None)
2018-04-20 03:16:30 INFO  BlockManager:54 - Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 172.24.20.2, 56082, None)
2018-04-20 03:16:30 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6b00ad9{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
    Exception in thread "receiver-supervisor-future-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.initializeLogIfNecessary(TwitterInputDStream.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.log(TwitterInputDStream.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.logInfo(TwitterInputDStream.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.onStop(TwitterInputDStream.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.stopReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor$$anonfun$restartReceiver$1.apply$mcV$sp(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor$$anonfun$restartReceiver$1.apply(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor$$anonfun$restartReceiver$1.apply(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:189)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1524208600000 ms
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1524208610000 ms
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
```

I found the related thread [Spark Program finding Popular HashTags from twiiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740964/spark-program-finding-popular-hashtags-from-twiiter) but no solution. Can someone from the community elaborate the error and how to resolve it?